# How to put checkboxes on separate lines and make the checkbox input bigger

Tags: html, checkbox

How can I put each individual checkbox and label on separate lines? I've tried everything.

Here's my markup:

```html
<label>What would you like to see improved? <label class="optional">(Check all that apply)</label>
<input value="1" type="checkbox">Front-end Projects</input>
<input value="2" type="checkbox">Back-end Projects</input>
<input value="3" type="checkbox">Data Visualization</input>
<input value="4" type="checkbox">Challenges</input>
<input value="5" type="checkbox">Open Source Community</input>
<input value="6" type="checkbox">Gitter help rooms</input>
<input value="7" type="checkbox">Videos</input>
<input value="10" type="checkbox">City Meetups</input>
<input value="11" type="checkbox">Wiki</input>
<input value="12" type="checkbox">Forum</input>
<input value="13" type="checkbox">Additional Courses</input>
```

Comment: Please use a [Markup Validator](https://validator.w3.org/)! Your Markup is invalid. An `<input>` is an empty tag (replaced element) and as such has no closing tag. `</input>` therefore is invalid as it does not exist.

Answer (score 1):

`<input>` doesn't have an end tag <del>`</input>`</del>. There's two ways to use a `<label>` that's valid:

1. Wrap it around a form control

   ```html
   <label> <input> </label>
   ```
2. Add an `#id` to the form control and `for` attribute to the `<label>`

   ```html
   <input id='data'> <label for="data">Data</label>
   ```

In order to change the size of a checkbox or radio button use CSS property [`transform`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform) and function value [`scale()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-function/scale) you'll need [`translateY()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-function/translateY) in order to adjust their vertical position as well.

You can make a new line-break by adding a `<br>` in HTML. See example.

```html
<style>
  [type='checkbox'] {
    transform: scale(1.25) translateY(0.75px);
  }
</style>
<fieldset>
  <legend>What would you like to see improved? (Check all that apply)</legend>
  <input id="chx1" type="checkbox"> <label for="chx1">Front-end Projects</label><br>
  <input id="chx2" type="checkbox"> <label for="chx2">Back-end Projects</label><br>
  <input id="chx3" type="checkbox"> <label for="chx3">Data Visualization</label><br>
  <input id="chx4" type="checkbox"> <label for="chx4">Challenges</label><br>
  <input id="chx5" type="checkbox"> <label for="chx5">Open Source Community</label>
</fieldset>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to adjust your markup a bit. Firstly, the `<label>` should not be used to group a collection of inputs, it should be used to describe which each input is.

Labels and checkbox input fields are by default, `inline`, so they would not go on separate lines without either some CSS making it block-level, or placing it inside a block-level element such as a `<div>`.

As for the checkbox size, this isn't so straightforward. You have to essentially mimic the checkbox by using pseudo-elements (`:before` or `after`) inside a label to make it selectable.

I've made one using your content below.

```css
.form-control {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1em auto;
  gap: 0.5em;
}

/* Make a gap between each option */
.form-control + .form-control {
  margin-top: 1em;
}

input[type="checkbox"] {
  appearance: none;
  background-color: #fff;
  margin: 0;
  font: inherit;
  color: currentColor;
  width: 1.15em;
  height: 1.15em;
  border: 0.15em solid currentColor;
  border-radius: 0.15em;
  transform: translateY(-0.075em);
  display: grid;
  place-content: center;
}

input[type="checkbox"]::before {
  content: "";
  width: 0.65em;
  height: 0.65em;
  transform: scale(0);
  box-shadow: inset 1em 1em black;
}

input[type="checkbox"]::before {
  content: "";
  width: 0.65em;
  height: 0.65em;
  transform: scale(0);
  box-shadow: inset 1em 1em black;
}

input[type="checkbox"]:checked::before {
  transform: scale(1);
}
```

```html
<p>What would you like to see improved? <span class="optional">(Check all that apply)</span></p>
<label class="form-control"><input type="checkbox" value="1">Front-end Projects</label>
<label class="form-control"><input type="checkbox" value="2">Back-end Projects</label>
<label class="form-control"><input type="checkbox" value="3">Data Visualization</label>
<label class="form-control"><input type="checkbox" value="4">Challenges</label>
<label class="form-control"><input type="checkbox" value="5">Open Source Community</label>
<label class="form-control"><input type="checkbox" value="6">Gitter help rooms</label>
<label class="form-control"><input type="checkbox" value="7">Videos</label>
<label class="form-control"><input type="checkbox" value="8">City Meetups</label>
<label class="form-control"><input type="checkbox" value="9">Wiki</label>
<label class="form-control"><input type="checkbox" value="10">Forum</label>
<label class="form-control"><input type="checkbox" value="11">Additional Courses</label>
```